# Solaris 11 reduce package group from large-server to minimal-server

Tags: solaris

I installed Solaris 11.4 with the text installer image. Maybe I missed the moment when it asked me about the installed software, but now I have 13GB installed for large-server. Instead I want to reduce all the software to the package group minimal-server, but haven't find any way to do so.

Comment: The Solaris text installer installs a pre-determined set of software - it doesn't ask what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37838_01/html/E60979/gnzqk.html shows how to use the command `pkg exact-install` to do this.